# Why use double pointer when inserting node in sorted order in linkedlist?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

```
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next; 
};

int insert_asc(node **phead, int data) {
    node **traser;
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newnode == 0)
        return 0;
    newnode->data = data;

    for (traser = phead; *traser != 0; traser = &(*traser)->next)
        if (data <= (*traser)->data)
            break;

    newnode->next = *traser;
    *traser = newnode;
    return 1;
}
```

The confusing part for me is when you dereference a double pointer `traser`.
how come `(*traser)->next` holds the next node's address? 
and what exactly is `*traser` here?

Comment: Post a minimal, compilable code.

Comment: `traser` is a way to keep track of the `next` pointer of the previous node. To insert in the middle of a list you need to modify the link from the previous node to your new node.

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on the code. It could also help if you try to do all the operations using a simple "linked list" on paper.

Comment: When chatting with the duck, also look at [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double pointers are used in the posted code for two separate purposes:

- `node **phead`: the head of the list is passed by referenced so it can be updated by `insert_asc` if the new node must be inserted at the head of the list. Passing by reference is not possible in C, the idiomatic way to achieve it is to pass a pointer to the value to be updated by the function, hence a double pointer `phead`.
- `node **traser`: To avoid making a special case of the empty list and the insertion at the head of the list, the programmer uses a pointer to keep track of the place to insert the new node. `traser` first points to the head of the list which in this case is the value of `phead` and is updated to point to the link between nodes, the `next` member of the current node, when it is determined that the new node must be inserted after the current one. This is an elegant way to implement insertion without a special case. C allows thanks to pointers, it is not possible in java nor javascript because these language do not have generalised pointers.

Note however that the code could be make more readable by use `NULL` instead of `0` when comparing pointers:

```c
typedef struct node node;
struct node {
    int data;
    node *next; 
};

int insert_asc(node **phead, int data) {
    node **traser;
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newnode == NULL)
        return 0;
    newnode->data = data;

    for (traser = phead; *traser != NULL; traser = &(*traser)->next) {
        if (data <= (*traser)->data)
            break;
    }
    newnode->next = *traser;
    *traser = newnode;
    return 1;
}
```

Note also that new nodes with a given value of `data` are inserted before nodes with the same `data` value. It does not make a difference in this case and may be a little faster for lists with many duplicates, but if the payload was more elaborate, this insertion method would implement a non-stable sort, whereas using `<` instead of `<=` would make the sort stable.

For illustration, here is alternative implementation that does not use a double pointer for the insertion point and needs extra tests for the special cases:

```c
int insert_asc(node **phead, int data) {
    node *cur;
    node *newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (newnode == NULL)
        return 0;
    newnode->data = data;

    cur = *phead;
    if (cur == NULL || cur->next == NULL) {
       newnode->next = cur;
       *phead = newnode;
    } else {
        while (cur->next != NULL && data < cur->next->data)
            cur = cur->next;
        newnode->next = cur->next;
        cur->next = newnode;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a double pointer here in order to keep track of the head of your list.

If you were using a simple pointer here and exchanged the nodes, you would risk loosing the address of some nodes of your list.

This is because if you were passing a simple pointer to the head of your list, you would then manipulate a copy of you head address in your function, therefore when you exchange positions in your function, the address of your head would still be the same, if you exchanged the head with another node, then the address of all nodes before the old head would be lost after your function modifies your list.

Edit: [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/c.html#mode=edit) is a tool that helped me understanding the behavior of linked list quite easily thanks to its excellent visualization tool, I would highly recommend you to use it.

Comment: The question is not really about the head of the list. It could easily be done with a single pointer `node *prev` that holds the address of previous node instead of previous node's `.next` element.

Comment: It's fair, he is answering the question asked in the title, which seems to vary from the one asked at the end of the question. However, you pass the *address of* the list pointer so it can be changed in the function and the change visible back in the caller. If you simply passed the pointer itself, the function would receive a copy and any changes made would be lost on function return until the updated list pointer was returned and assigned back in the caller. Bottom line, you don't risk losing *"some node"* you risk losing your *"list address"*.